# Не запускается телеграм бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Подскажите плиз, у меня есть такой код:

```
token = 'мой токен'
bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
chat_id = 'чат'
my_chat = 'чат'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=token)
```

Закинул бота на сервер, он выдаёт мне ошибку:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'
```

Но это не только ошибка на сервере, если я копирую код в другой Pycharm проект , выходит такая же ошибка, подскажите, может я библиотеку не подключил какую то? В основном проекте все работает.
Добавлю, что ошибку пишет на последней строке

Comment: Все решилось, нашёл тему отличающуюся от этой но помогло
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64951712/telebot-object-has-no-attribute-message-handler

Answer (score -1):

Для использования API телеграма в Python, никаких библиотек дополнительно подключать не нужно. Вот мое использование

```
        url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<yourid>:<token>/sendMessage'
        params = {"chat_id":"<chatid>", "parse_mode":"HTML", "text":"<b>Project: </b><code><i>" + name + "</i></code>\n<b>Result: </b><strong><i>" + result + "</i></strong>"}
        requests.post(url, data = params)
```

Comment: Спасибо таким способом не хотелось что то ,да и не получилось, был похожий способ, но там запрещено было вроде как